# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

**I am new to programming**

**INDEX.JS**

```js
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const multer = require("multer")
const app = express()
const maxSize = 1 * 1000 * 1000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        cb(null, "uploads")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now()+".pdf")
    }
})
    
var upload = multer({storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: maxSize }}).array('fileUpload', 2);  

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/uploads/:filename", (req, res) => {
    let filename = req.params.filename;
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/uploads/" + filename)
});

app.post("/upload",function (req, res, next) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            let str = `<p>Success, pdf uploaded!</p>
                <p><a href="${req.file.path}">View File</a></p>`;
            res.send(str)
        }
    })
})




app.listen(9000,function(error) {
    if(error) throw error
        console.log("Server created Successfully on PORT 9000")
        console.log("http://localhost:9000")
})
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" hidden="hidden" multiple /> <br>
        <button type="button" id="button1">UPLOAD FILES</button>
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**MAIN.JS**

```js
const customBtn = document.getElementById("button1");
const fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload")

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fileUpload.click();
});

fileUpload.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (fileUpload.value) {
    customBtn.innerHTML = fileUpload.value.match(
      /[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/
    )[1];
  } else {
    customBtn.innerHTML = "No file chosen, yet.";
  }
});
```

When I run INDEX.js i get the following error **Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')** The pdfs get uploaded to my UPLOADS folder but I still get the error **Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')**

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal in the folder where your code is and try running `npm install`.

Comment: That did not work